# Save html5 canvas as image in server

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas

I had a html5 canvas with an image. Peoples can edit/ adjust image using javascript. After all done they must have an option to post that image in their Facebook wall. As of my best knowledge we can meet the requirement like this

```
Save Canvas data as image in to my server      -->     Post to Facebook with its image URL   -->    Delete the image on call back.
```

First of all is this assumption is correct and second is

How to save the HTML 5 Canvas to a png image using javascript on a button click ?
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to save your canvas as a specific image format

```
var mycanvas = document.getElementById("whatever"); //get your canvas
var image    = mycanvas.toDataURL("image/png"); //Convert the canvas to image, currently converting to .png
```

Comment: +1 - But worth noting that the resulting image is base64 encoded and will be of higher size than a binary encoded PNG. Maybe a good idea to native encode it on the server before sending to FB.

Comment: if so I cant upload that to facebook ? any prob ?

Comment: @techfoobar can you help a little how to native encode the image in server ?

Comment: @ramesh - depends on the server side technology you are using (PHP, Java, Node.Js, ASP.NEt etc.). In any case, you can use something like image magick to load and save the image in native format (regardless of the platform, image magcik will be available as a forkable command line process i believe)

Comment: hi guys .. one more doubt ... how to save this created image in server  via a button click ?

Comment: @ramesh this will help you out http://www.icebluemonkey.com/blog/javascript/saving-your-html5-canvas-drawing-to-a-png/

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to convert your image to base64 format using Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

now through PHP convert in to image and save it to server

```
file_put_contents("myimage.jpg", base64_decode(explode(",", $_GET['data'])[1]));
```

That's all